# Intended giving of Tzedaka when the cause disappears

Tags: halacha, tzedakah-charity

Related to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/43549/440), what if after deciding to donate Tzedaka to a cause, but before actually getting to do it, the cause goes away. E.g. the poor person dies, the organization closes down, etc.

Should the money be giving to a different place? Does there have to be a similarity between them (e.g. if it was intended for a poor person, find another poor person, don't donate it to a seforim library).